# how to dynamically extract data from dropdown lists or multiple textboxes using import.io

Tags: api, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-crawlers, import.io

I am making an API wherein I want to dynamically get data from the site **http://transportformumbai.com/mumbai_local_train.php**

Depending on start and end station and timings I want to get the list of all available trains along with the ***[table given by clicking on viewroute column](http://transportformumbai.com/get_schedule_new.php?user_route=western&start_station=khar_road&end_station=malad&start_time=00&end_time=18)*** table. i.e. ***[for eg.](http://transportformumbai.com/view_route_new.php?trainno=BYR1097&user_route=western&train_origin=Churchgate&train_end=Bhayandar&train_speed=S)***

I am using **import.io connector**... But it **works well with a single textbox but not with multiple textboxes ([Refer this link](http://www.taxifarefinder.com/main.php?city=Mumbai-India))or dropdown lists**...

Can anyone guide what should I do next...
Apart from import.io is there anyother alternative?

I am a newbie working with crawlers... So please justify your answer.

What is web scraping... Do I have to use web scraper??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you look in the URL bar the parameters for destination and time are defined there (highlighted below), so you don't need to worry about drop down menus, or using a Connector.

Use an Extractor on this page:

http://transportformumbai.com/get_schedule_new.php?user_route=western&**start_station=khar_road**&**end_station=malad**&**start_time=00**&**end_time=18**

Train it to get every column - note that the view route column contains links.

You can create a separate Extractor for the "view route" page:

http://transportformumbai.com/view_route_new.php?trainno=BYR1097&user_route=western&train_origin=Churchgate&train_end=Bhayandar&train_speed=S

Now you should "Chain" the second Extractor to the first one and it will pull that information from every link on the first one.

If you want to choose different destinations and times, just change the URL parameters of the original link.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/613374-how-do-i-get-data-behind-dropdown-menus

Your best bet here seems to have an API for every URL combination. You have to analyze the URL structure.